# Are there studies that compare the accuracy of forecasters that are asked to state probabilities vs. forecasters that are asked to state odds?

Tags: measurement, performance

The Good Judgement project asks it's forecasters to estimate the likelihood of events occurring by asking them for probabilities (20%, 60%...). Sport betting usually communicates the odds of an event (1:4, 2:3).

Is there any research done to see whether forecasters using either method make better predictions? Whether either method leads to a lower Briers score?